# Why was my poll question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, polling

I'm a beginner/intermediate SO user and I thought [this was a good legit question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911408/the-best-text-editor-for-programmers-closed). Even though it was a bit subjective. I'm a CS student and my thinking was to go learn the few editors that got the most up votes as those would naturally be the editors that lots of programmers at SO considered to be the best. It seems like this would be valuable for all CS students who haven't used lots of editors yet. But it was closed before any real answers could be given. My question is why?

Comment: Questions that ask "what is the best X" are often subjective and argumentative.  "What is the best text editor?" is especially argumentative, in no small part because some people don't understand that vi is far superior to Emacs.

Comment: haha, ok. I understand the point of this question isn't to find "one editor to rule them all" but to weed out the "bad" editors. what's wrong with that?

Comment: It seems that [the older comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911408/the-best-text-editor-for-programmers-closed) (and your own *"This is completely subjective"*) at that question actually already answer this?

Comment: :: careful enters "James McNellis" on *The List* ::

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the FAQ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

Comment: @dmckee which list are you referring to. [This one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_List_(South_Park)?

Comment: @Pekka: Hmm....depends. Can I put James below me?

Comment: @dmckee I guess you can!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If  you didn't know about the handling of subjective questions, and if you would have searched for an answer yourself but failed to find one, then STILL it should have been closed as you totally ignored the warning and the looooooong list of related questions you were shown:
[image: Listen to the feedback!]

Comment: I think a lot of people totally miss that list for all kinds of questions.

Comment: you should also put a circle around `The question you've been asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed`

Comment: @Tobias, and a set of blinking arrows, too? Maybe a MIDI file of a siren looping in the background? At some point, you can't do any more.

Comment: @Popular MIDI files will play differently from computer to computer. You need MP3

Comment: @Pekka, maybe we can get Jeff to show up at their houses with a giant `S` (you know, for "subjective").

Comment: @Popular the `S` is such a versatile letter. So many uses around the house

Comment: Related: [<blink> tag in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928103/blink-tag-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 reasons I can see :

- It's subjective, Stack Overflow isn't made for subjective questions. Even though there are tons of subjective questions (mostly old ones) that aren't closed, that doesn't mean you should start new one.
- There are tons of duplicates of that question

[Windows-based Text Editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155/windows-based-text-editors)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215/what-are-the-best-alternatives-to-notepad
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199177/what-are-the-good-free-programming-text-editors-for-windows
[Good text/code editor for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148934/good-text-code-editor-for-linux-closed)

And there are more that are about editors for specific language.

Answer (score 5):

> Let's settle this debate once and for all.

This isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

> This is completely subjective so take it with a grain of salt.

Again, not what Stack Overflow is for.  If we're not supposed to take your question seriously, why not just close it?

This is covered in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> Avoid asking subjective or argumentative questions. If you must ask a subjective question, make sure it meets the [six guidelines for great subjective questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), or it will be closed.