# Area 51: typo in the answer ratio description

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, spelling

I am looking at [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1269/english-language-usage) right now. To the right of the "3.0 answer ratio" box, it says:

> Excellent – 2.5 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question is worrying. **In** a healthy site, questions receive multiple answers and the best answer is voted to the top.

I have a feeling that the "in" should be an "on".

Comment: Preemptive snarky comment: [Jeff will personally come to my house and bludgeon me to death with a giant O](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791).

Comment: Jeff the Letter Bludgeoner!

Comment: nah, he'll use his `S`. In addition to representing plurals, it's good for spelling, semantics and [subjective](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67339/why-was-my-poll-question-closed/#comment-161807)

Comment: If you are a denizen of the "English Language and Usage" site, then it seems like "in" is appropriate.

Comment: As a denizen of English Language and Usage, I humbly direct you to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/) which highlights the differences between *in*, *on*, and *at*. There's nothing inherently wrong with being active *in* meta and working hard *in* SO, but *on* is much more common and much more SFW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In honor of this bug's upcoming third anniversary, we fixed the grammar - enjoy!